# Вывод постов в зависимости от рубрики (замена ACF)

Tags: php, html, wordpress, веб-программирование, acf

Нашел видео [Wordpress](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1HMZf2dR5ow).  В нем с 24:00 по 29:00 используется плагин ACF (см. также 6:40-7:00, 8:00-9:30, 10:30-12:40, 20:40-24:00). Есть следующий вариант: карточки людей оформлять просто в виде записей (постов) (не создавая для постов новых типов с помощью `register_customposttype_init`, `register_post_type`), задавая для них определенную рубрику (категорию), а затем в цикле проверять тип поста (рубрику) и в зависимости от значения рубрики выводить их в определенном месте (для данного значения рубрики). Каким образом можно проверить рубрику поста и осуществить вывод поста в зависимости от рубрики? Как я понимаю нужно использовать конструкцию вида

```
if (have_posts) (while(have_posts) {
   if (wordpress_check_category(current_post)) {
   echo current_post; /*а точнее использовать the_title, the_content и т.д.*/
}
}
```

Каким образом это записывается в wordpress?

Comment: С помощью `WP_Query()`, [документация с примерами](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#taxonomies)

Comment: @Simon вы не поняли вопроса. как осуществить вывод постов в зависимости от рубрики? (или в качестве таксономии нужно использовать рубрику)

Comment: Рубрика -- это term. Вы можете использовать это таким образом как и описано в первой строке, добавив в массив аргументов `'category' => 'some-category-slug'`, либо как описано ниже `tax_query` где можно найти больше параметров.

Comment: @Simon а можно как-нибудь сделать, используя мою логику?

Comment: Можете использовать или хук [pre_get_posts()](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/pre_get_posts), ну или проверять в самом цикле, только используйте [in_category](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/).

Comment: @Simon а get_posts с указанием category можно использовать?

Comment: Можно, [документация](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_posts#category)